# Systematic deletion of files from RAID drive

Tags: raid, mac, apple

I have a client with a Mac Pro and an two undetermined RAID storage systems from Areca, running off of an internal MRAID card. They are currently using the primary RAID array for working files, and the secondary for backups. However, in recent weeks, files have been systematically been deleted off of the working RAID. Deletions do not appear in the console anywhere, either. It always happens in alphabetical order. We have rebuilt the Mac Pro, thinking there might be a fault, but to no avail.

The primary RAID is also shared on the network (about 4 users, all in the same room), but there is no external network access to the device.

Any ideas greatly appreciated as to what might be causing this.

Comment: No file system logging capabilities on the mac? WIndows has them - normally off (it is a crapton of stuff that gets logged) but you can turn them on. Maybe OSX has something similar?

Comment: Mac OS X does indeed have comprehensive file logging - but in this case, nothing is being logged.